# Custom or operation in Java

Tags: java, boolean-operations

For a project in Java, I create a custom Boolean class (named Result) which can have three value : True, False, or Undefined. 
I have defined two function : "or" and "and" with rules :

```
    public static Result or(Result r1, Result r2) {
        if(r1.isTrue() || r2.isTrue()){
            return V(); //new Result with value "True";
        } else if(r1.isUndefined() || r2.isUndefined()) {
            return U(); //new Result with value "Undefined";
        }  else {
            return F(); //new Result with value "False";
        }
    }

    public static Result and(Result r1, Result r2) {
        if(r1.isFalse() || r2.isFalse()){
            return F(); //new Result with value "False";
        } else if(r1.isUndefined() || r2.isUndefined()) {
            return U();//new Result with value "Undefined";
        }  else {
            return V(); //new Result with value "True";
        }
    }
```

That work, but for many cases, it's not efficient because I need to compute the value of the two Result before compute return of "or" or "and" :

if I do

```
if(f1() || f2()){

}
```

and result of f1() is True, f2() will never be executed to save computation time.

Is there a solution to have the same behaviour with my custom class?

Comment: yes. Run it and save the result in a variable then use this variable in the condition

Comment: You can use `|` instead of `||` if you want to evaluate the second condition regardless of the first.

Comment: Why u want Custom boolean class , Next  the operator || is that if the left-hand operand results in true, the right-hand operand expression won't be evaluated.

Comment: @jhamon : I can do : `Result r1= f2();    if(r1.isTrue()){    return r1; } else {    Result r2=f2();    return Result.or(r1, r2); }` But I do many "or" and "and" in my code, and if I can, I prefer to not have to repeat that code each time.

Comment: @TanmayNaik : Because I need the "Undefined" value.

Comment: You are only evaluating them both if `r1` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Supplier` in order to get a 'delayed' execution of your `Result` class:

```
public static Result or(Supplier<Result> r1Supplier, Supplier<Result> r2Supplier) {
        Result r1 = r1Supplier.get();
        if(r1.isTrue()){
            return V(); //new Result with value "True";
        } else if(r1.isUndefined()) {
            return U(); //new Result with value "Undefined";
        }  else {
            // only here you need to handle r2 
            Result r2 = r2Supplier.get();
            if(r2.isTrue()){
                return V(); //new Result with value "True";
            } else if(r2.isUndefined()) {
                return U(); //new Result with value "Undefined";
            }  else {
                return F();
            }
        }
    }
```

It can be cleaned up a bit and ordered better, but you get the hang of it

Comment: You probably mean Supplier?

Comment: When r1=True and r2=Unknown, OP's `or` returns Unknown. But your `or` returns True.

Comment: @saka1029 - just showing the general idea of using supplier for delayed/conditional execution, the details are less important and I'm sure he can handle